# Created function to download all data from a website in a csv file for later use. How to reload the data to the website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Okay so i've created this simple website. We have 10 input fields and we can save whatever value they have in a csv file for later use. Basically what i get is a csv file that gives me data that looks like that for example:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Okay so now i have my csv file locally stored. Now i shut down my computer come back another day and want to load my locally stored csv file so that the input shows what was in there when i saved the csv file. How do i achieve this?

```js
//function to download the input as a csv file 
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
  var csvFile;
  var downloadLink;
  // CSV file
  csvFile = new Blob([csv], {
    type: "text/csv"
  });
  // Download link
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  // File name
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  // Create a link to the file
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
  // Hide download link
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  // Add the link to DOM
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  // Click download link
  downloadLink.click();
}

function exportDataToCSV() {
  var data1 = $("#input1").val();
  var data2 = $("#input2").val();
  var data3 = $("#input3").val();
  var data4 = $("#input4").val();
  var data5 = $("#input5").val();
  var data6 = $("#input6").val();
  var data7 = $("#input7").val();
  var data8 = $("#input8").val();
  var data9 = $("#input9").val();
  var data10 = $("#input10").val();
  var csv = [];
  var dataArray = [];

  dataArray.push(data1);
  dataArray.push(data2);
  dataArray.push(data3);
  dataArray.push(data4);
  dataArray.push(data5);
  dataArray.push(data6);
  dataArray.push(data7);
  dataArray.push(data8);
  dataArray.push(data9);
  dataArray.push(data10);

  csv.push(dataArray);

  var temp_fname = ""
  if (localStorage.fileName != undefined) {
    temp_fname = prompt("Project name: ", localStorage.fileName);
  } else {
    temp_fname = prompt("Project name: ", "");
  }
  if (temp_fname != null) {
    filename = temp_fname + ".csv";
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
  }
}

//Save Button 
$("#save").click(function() {
  exportDataToCSV();
})


// no closing on accident
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.alert("Test");
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onbeforeunload=" return 'Are you really want to perform the action?'">
  <h1 style="color: green">
    This is a simple TestPage
  </h1>
  <b>Please Type in some inputs so that they can be saved and loaded for later</b>
  <p> </p>
  <input id="input1">
  <input id="input2">
  <input id="input3">
  <input id="input4">
  <input id="input5">
  <input id="input6">
  <input id="input7">
  <input id="input8">
  <input id="input9">
  <input id="input10">
  <br><br><br>
  <button id="save"> Save </button>
  <button id="load"> Load </button>
</body>
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <title> 
        TestPage for inputs
    </title> 
</head> 

<body onbeforeunload=" return 'Are you really want to perform the action?'"> 
    <h1 style="color: green"> 
        This is a simple TestPage 
    </h1> 

    <b>Please Type in some inputs so that they can be saved and loaded for later</b> 

    <p> 

    </p> 

    <input id = "input1">
    <input id = "input2">
    <input id = "input3">
    <input id = "input4">
    <input id = "input5">
    <input id = "input6">
    <input id = "input7">
    <input id = "input8">
    <input id = "input9">
    <input id = "input10">
    <br><br><br>

    <button id = "save"> Save </button> 
    <button id = "load"> Load </button> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 


    //function to download the input as a csv file 
    function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;
    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});
    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
   // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}

function exportDataToCSV ()

{

var data1 = $("#input1").val();
var data2 = $("#input2").val();
var data3 = $("#input3").val();
var data4 = $("#input4").val();
var data5 = $("#input5").val();
var data6 = $("#input6").val();
var data7 = $("#input7").val();
var data8 = $("#input8").val();
var data9 = $("#input9").val();
var data10 = $("#input10").val();



var csv = [];

var dataArray = [];

dataArray.push(data1);
dataArray.push(data2);
dataArray.push(data3);
dataArray.push(data4);
dataArray.push(data5);
dataArray.push(data6);
dataArray.push(data7);
dataArray.push(data8);
dataArray.push(data9);
dataArray.push(data10);

csv.push(dataArray);

var temp_fname =""
    if (localStorage.fileName!=undefined) {
        temp_fname = prompt("Project name: ", localStorage.fileName);
    } else {
        temp_fname = prompt("Project name: ", "");
    }
    if (temp_fname != null) {
        filename = temp_fname+".csv";
        downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
    }

}



//Save Button 
$("#save").click(function(){
exportDataToCSV();

})  






        // no closing on accident
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.alert("Test");
            e.returnValue = ''; 
        });


    </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Need more information. Do you want the loaded data unique for each user that visits the website? So if person A fills out the form they get the results when they reload and person B fills out different information, they get their results?

Comment: @disinfor it doesnt matter. If Person A fills out the form and downloads the csv data he saves it locally on his computer.so Person A can load it and get the results or send the csv file to Person B who also can load it and get the same results as Person A. It doesnt matter which Person fills it out, it just matters which locally saved csv file was uploaded.

Comment: This is typically done using cookies.

Comment: @Kimo Your edits make the question much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1

On document load retrieve the csv file & parse it with jquery
Here is the link how to do that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });
});

function processData(allText) {
    var record_num = 5;  // or however many elements there are in each row
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var entries = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    var headings = entries.splice(0,record_num);
    while (entries.length>0) {
        var tarr = [];
        for (var j=0; j<record_num; j++) {
            tarr.push(headings[j]+":"+entries.shift());
        }
        lines.push(tarr);
    }
    // alert(lines);
}
```

**output**

```
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
value1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1
value1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2
```

For parsing it into json

var data = $.csv.toObjects(lines):

**output**

```
[
  { heading1:"value1_1",heading2:"value2_1",heading3:"value3_1",heading4:"value4_1",heading5:"value5_1" } 
  { heading1:"value1_2",heading2:"value2_2",heading3:"value3_2",heading4:"value4_2",heading5:"value5_2" }
]
```

Step 2 
Upon parsing the data, use jQuery to assign the values to your input tag e.g `input.value = parsedValue`

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add a code sample with a working example.